# Какой должна быть регулярка для RewriteRule что бы переписывать определенный GET-параметр?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Есть URL вида /news?page=3&utm=ex

Задача: перенаправлять все подобные URL на /news/page-3?utm=ex

При этом параметр page может стоять в любом месте, т.е. не обязательно быть первым после знака вопроса и конечно же он может быть единственным параметром, а может быть одним из набора...

Подскажите как сформировать правило RewriteRule

Comment: вам придется записать rewriteRule два раза для разного порядка параметров и еще один на случай когда он один. Либо вытащить page, но оставить его в строке параметров. это проще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

Поскольку, как я понял из условия, параметров может быть произвольное количество в произвольном порядке, то можно из запроса определять номер страницы и делать редирект на целевую страницу, с сохранением всех оригинальных параметров запроса(включая `page=N`):

Файл *.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bpage=(\d+)
RewriteRule .* /news/page-%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

**Вариант 2**

Если все-таки нужно параметр `page` убрать из параметров запроса при редиректе на целевую страницу, то это можно сделать через php-скрипт:

Файл *.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bpage=(\d+)
RewriteRule .* /rnews.php [L,QSA]
```

Файл *rnews.php*

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['page'];
unset($_GET['page']);
$query = http_build_query($_GET);
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header("Location: /news/page-{$page}?{$query}");
```